# Como carregar PartialView via Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC onde existe um método que retorna uma `PartialView`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAction(int param1, int param2)
{
   // ...
   // Código
   // ...

   MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document doc = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
   DocumentRenderer renderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
   PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer();
   pdfRenderer.PdfDocument = outPdf;
   pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer = renderer;

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

   pdfRenderer.Save(ms, false);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
   ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   ms.Flush();
   ms.Read(buffer, 0, (int)ms.Length);

   PdfFormatOptions pfo = ExportOptions.CreatePdfFormatOptions();
   pfo.CreateBookmarksFromGroupTree = true; //habilita tree

   return PartialView("PrintPdf", ms);
}
```

Minha **PartialView** `PrintPdf` está assim:

```
@using myProject.Enumerator
@model Stream

@{

    var file = Model.ToArray();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disopsition", "filename=" + ViewBag.FileName);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(file.ToArray());
}
```

Como podem ver, estou querendo retornar um PDF para a View onde tenho o seguinte Ajax:

```
<div id="conteudo-pdf" style="display:none;width:790px;height:590px;"></div>
```

// ...

```
 $.ajax({
     beforeSend: function () {
          LoadStart();
     },
     complete: function () {
          LoadStop();
     },
     contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController")',
     data: JSON.stringify(
         {
             param1: 1,
             param2: 2
         }),
     success: function (data) {
             $("#conteudo-pdf").empty();
             ShowDialog("Title", "#conteudo-pdf", "1024", "660");
             $("#conteudo-pdf").html(data);
         },
    timeout: 420000,
    fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
             if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                   alert('Failed from timeout');
             }
             alert("Error 007")
     }
});
```

// ...

```
function ShowDialog(title, idDiv, largura, altura) {
    $(idDiv).dialog({
        title: title,
        resizable: false,
        width: largura,
        height: altura,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: [{
            text: Resources.Fechar,
            click: function () {
                $(idDiv).attr("title", "");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    }).css("font-size", "10px").fadeIn("slow");

    ValidaForm();
}
```

Infelizmente não tem dado certo, pois a variável `data` sempre vem `null`. Já tentei enviar o `pdf` como `base64`, mas por ter muitos detalhes gráficos, acaba travando o navegador. Preciso de algo leve e simples, mas que mantenha minha `Action` como `POST`.

Comment: Você quer retornar o PDF para uma `div` ou quer abrir ele em uma página?

Comment: O objetivo era exibir ele na `div`, mas só de fazer o download já salvaria minha pele! O problema é que tenho um método `POST` e não tenho um arquivo físico, mas um `MemoryStream`...

Comment: Mas porque tem que ser `POST`? Você não pode abrir esse PDF com um link normal?

Comment: Tem que ser POST pois estou gerando um relatório que pode enviar muitos parâmetros, e além de uma URL muito grande não funcionar, fica visualmente feio...

Comment: Nenhum dos motivos faz sentido, mas vamos lá. Você já colocou um breakpoint na Action para ver se o Ajax está passando os parâmetros corretamente? Ela chega a retornar a `PartialView`? Retire o `POST` e abra na URL normalmente, para testar se está funcionando.